# UI5 SplitContainer switch mode (always show menu icon)

Tags: master-detail, mode, sapui5

I have a **UI5 SplitApp for iPad**. At the moment I run it in **HideMode**, so that my content is "fullscreen" and then the *Master View* can be opened by clicking the menu icon. But the Master is not part of the layout then. What I would like to do is make it possible to switch: If the Master is closed I want the detail fullscreen and if I open the Master it should be part of the Layout (Master/Detail) as in **ShowHideMode**.

What I have already tried:

```
<SplitApp id="idAppControl" beforeMasterOpen="changeMode" mode="HideMode">
```

Controller:

```
changeMode: function(e) {
        e.getSource().setMode(sap.m.SplitAppMode.ShowHideMode);
    },
```

This works fine to initially have this state:

[image]

and on tab change to this state (which is fine):
[image]

But I can't change back then. I tried to add a custom button and call sth like `hideMaster()` (which only works if in ShowHideMode and the device is in portrait mode :-/) ..

Do you have an idea how I could do that? Or an idea for an alternative approach with another control?

Answer (score 0):

This is a hack and use of private variable//not recommended.
let me know if it works else I will delete the answer

```
    onAfterRendering() {
            try {
                this._oShowMasterBtn.removeStyleClass('sapMSplitContainerMasterBtnHidden');
            } catch (e) {
                console.log("Failed to show the button" + e.message)
            }
        }
        //both may not be necessary
    onBeforeRendering() {
        try {
            this._oShowMasterBtn.removeStyleClass('sapMSplitContainerMasterBtnHidden');
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("Failed to show the button" + e.message)
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried adding/removing the "hidden" style classes before, it works with a timeout to remove the class you mentioned, but then the button does not fire press event (is just shown) anymore.. I think this solution will not be "stable" enough..